# How to calculate price when optional checkbox is clicked(using paypal payment form)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, forms, paypal

I have built an order form in which the user would enter in a company name, last name, email and an address and an optional checkbox for shipping priced at $19.99.  I downloaded the [paypal payment form module](http://www.hotdreamweaver.com/paypal-payment-form) for my dreamweaver cs5 program which converts the form into a paypal form.

The nice thing about this program is that it automatically creates a mysql database with all the input fields when a person clicks the "pay now" button It also generates the files automatically in a folder called "PPPaymentForm" which i then upload in the root of my site and gives me a backend as well so i can monitor all the payment transactions.

So back to my original issue, i need some way so that if a person decides to click the checkbox which is set at $19.99, that it will automatically add to the price which is set in an hidden input named "hdwppamount" where the value is set to $175.00. So therefor if the shipping option is clicked, the person would click the "Pay Now" button and would be redirected to the paypal payment page, with the new calculated price at $194.99.

I am not proficient with javascript or php, and tried many functions myself but nothing worked. Could someone help me with this please?

Thank You

```html
<form action="PPPaymentForm/PPPaymentForm.php" method="post" name="topchoiceform" id="topchoiceform">
  <input placeholder="Company Name" type="text" name="companyname" required>
  <input placeholder="First Name" type="text" name="firstname" required>
  <input placeholder="Last Name" type="text" name="lastname" required>
  <input placeholder="Email" type="email" name="email" required>
  <input placeholder="Address" type="text" name="address" required>
  <input type="checkbox" id="shipping" name='shipping' />$optional Shipping($19.99)
  <button name="submit" type="submit">Pay Now</button>

  <input type="hidden" name="hdwtablename" id="hdwtablename" value="1">
  <input type="hidden" name="hdwppproductname" id="hdwppproductname" value="Basic 175 Plan">
  <input type="hidden" name="hdwppamount" id="hdwppamount" value="175">
  <input type="hidden" name="hdwppcurrency" id="hdwppcurrency" value="USD">
  <input type="hidden" name="hdwpplanguage" id="hdwpplanguage" value="en_US">
  <input type="hidden" name="hdwok" id="hdwok" value="">
  <input type="hidden" name="hdwemail" id="hdwemail" value="email+gmail.com">
  <input type="hidden" name="hdwnook" id="hdwnook" value="http://">
  <input type="hidden" name="hdwactivation_email" id="hdwactivation_email" value="email">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, we detect when the shipping checkbox is changed, then we check to see if it is in a checked state. If it is in a checked state, we add the shipping cost to the hidden text box. We also need to reset the value if the user changes their mind about shipping so you need a basic IF ELSE condition on it.

Try this:

```
$('#shipping').change(function(){
    var hdwppamount = Number($("#hdwppamount").val())
    var shippingcost = 19.99;

     if (this.checked) {
        $("#hdwppamount").val(hdwppamount+shippingcost)
     } else {
        $("#hdwppamount").val(hdwppamount-shippingcost)
     }
})
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/rdawkins/8qrm3mf1/14/

Comment: That did the trick, thanks so much!

Comment: Glad I could help! Please accept the answer if it worked for you ;)

Comment: Hey Bruno, thanks for your help again.  I need your help again. So the calculation is great, but i need a workaround now.  What i need now is a way so that when a person chooses the optional shipping method, it would then display the shipping fee in the order summary paypal page, separate from the price of the product. So now instead of just having a calculated amount for both the price and shipping being displayed, they will now be separate with the price set(in this case $175) and the shipping fee at $19.99, with the item total for both($194.99) 

Hope you can help:)

Comment: show us what you have tried. This site is for troubleshooting, not to have people write your code. Also, accept the answer if it solved your original question by clicking the checkmark arrow.

Comment: Hi Bruno, i tried some different scenarios and techniques but could not acheive this, fortunately this is actually no longer needed. Thank you so much for your help though.

I will continue to try and see if i could achieve this myself.

Thank You